# How to select element has id start and end with specific text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I have multiple divs with ids like `course1_popup`, `course2_popup`, `course3_popup`. I want to make a function something like

```
$('#course*_popup').hide();
```

so that all `course*_popup` divs should hide but this is not working. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the combination of attribute [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [ends with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selectors.

```
$('[id^="course"][id$="_popup"]').hide();
```

---

**FYI :** It would be much better to use a common class for the group of elements for such things.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way: Give all the same class like *course_popup* and then:

```
$('.course_popup').hide()
```

Other solution was postet a sec ago ;)